# How to use XTextFormatter to print multiple paragraphs

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, pdfsharp, pdfsharpcore

Both PDFsharp and PdfSharpCore provide the `XTextFormatter` class. This class is a lifesaver when it comes to printing blocks that require word wrap.

But here's my question: What if I need to print multiple paragraphs? How can I determine where the bottom of the paragraph just printed is?

`XTextFormatter.DrawString()` returns `void`, so it doesn't tell me how far down it got. And there are no overloads that accept a new Y position or rectangle. And the only similar property, `LayoutRectangle`, simply contains the rectangle that I passed to `DrawString()`. And `XTextFormatter` has no `MeasureString()` method.

So how is it possible to print multiple paragraphs, one just below the previous?

Comment: The `XTextFormatter` class is meant as a sample to get you started. Take the source and adapt it to your needs. An improved version can be found here: https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3192

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this is not supported. Surprisingly, the author of the `XTextFormatter` class chooses not to expose this information and keeps the current Y position internal to that class.

Fortunately, both PDFsharp and PdfSharpCore are open source. You can download the `XTextFormatter` code and tweak it to your heart's content. Or you can work from [the version in this discussion](https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3147).

Comment: Newer version here: https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3192